# Getting an inteccorect Syntax error on sp_UpdateStockItemAmount

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm currently working on having two SQL queries running during a removal of items in an order currently. One to remove the item from the order table and the other to update the stock on a different table. This is what I've written:

```
public int DeleteItem(int stockItemId)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM DBO.OrderItems  WHERE stockItemId=@stockItemId  sp_UpdateStockItemAmount @Id, 1", //sp_SelectStockItems, @Id, 1
            connection))
            
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stockItemId", stockItemId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", stockItemId);
            connection.Open();

            int result = -1;

            try
            {
                result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error.Message.ToString());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I'm running into the following error when I try to execute this via a button press:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Error: Incorrect syntax near 'sp_UpdateStockItemAmount'.
```

sp_UpdateStockItemAmount is the stored procedure I need to work with that either adds 1 to the instock column or removes 1 stock.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two SQL instructions in one line and `sp_UpdateStockItemAmount` is not recognized as stored procedure invocation

add `exec`:

```
"DELETE FROM DBO.OrderItems WHERE stockItemId=@stockItemId; exec sp_UpdateStockItemAmount @Id, 1"
```